# (node:21) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: "escapeHtml" is not allowed

Tags: node.js, api-gateway

(node:21) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: "escapeHtml" is not allowed     at internals.Object.checkOptions (/opt/api-gateway/node_modules/joi/lib/types/any/index.js:95:19)     at internals.Object._validateWithOptions (/opt/api-gateway/node_modules/joi/lib/types/any/index.js:663:18)     at module.exports.internals.Any.root.validate (/opt/api-gateway/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/joi/lib/index.js:138:23)     at Object.internals.input (/opt/api-gateway/node_modules/hapi/lib/validation.js:143:20)     at exports.headers (/opt/api-gateway/node_modules/hapi/lib/validation.js:52:22)     at each (/opt/api-gateway/node_modules/hapi/lib/request.js:399:16)     at iterate (/opt/api-gateway/node_modules/items/lib/index.js:31:13)     at done (/opt/api-gateway/node_modules/items/lib/index.js:23:25)     at authenticated (/opt/api-gateway/node_modules/hapi/lib/auth.js:414:20)     at internals.Authenticator.validate (/opt/api-gateway/node_modules/hapi/lib/auth.js:421:20) (node:21) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:21) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. (node:21) [DEP0097] DeprecationWarning: Using a domain property in MakeCallback is deprecated. Use the async_context variant of MakeCallback or the AsyncResource class instead.

can anyone help me for the above error .Im getting this issue after building the app